# Calculate Equation From Seperate Tables Data

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I'm working on my senior High School Project and am reaching out to the community for help! (As my teacher doesn't know the answer to my question).

I have a simple "Products" table as shown below:

[image: Products table image]

I also have a "Orders" table shown below:

[image: Orders table image]

**Is there a way I can create a field in the "Orders" table named "Total Cost", and make that automaticly calculate the total cost from all the products selected?**

Comment: Please provide us a SQL command how you created Products and Orders table.

Comment: Bad idea. Use a query to do your calculations.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Comment: Many SQL DBMSs have "computed"/"calculated" columns whose value for a row is calculated by the DBMS as a function of the columns of the row. Of course, their use interacts with other details of the particular DBMS. Unfortunately support for such integrity & atomicity is typically poorly supported. (There is no meaningful violation of NFs because a table with such columns is just a view of what the table would be without the columns.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I would advise against storing calculated values, and would also **strongly advise against** using [calculated fields in tables](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/add-a-calculated-field-to-a-table-14a60733-2580-48c2-b402-6de54fafbde3). In general, [calculations should be performed by queries](http://allenbrowne.com/casu-14.html).

I would also strongly advise against the use of multivalued fields, as your images appear to show.

---

In general, when following the rules of [database normalisation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/283878/description-of-the-database-normalization-basics), most sales databases are structured in a very similar manner, containing with the following main tables (amongst others):

- Products (aka Stock Items)
- Customers
- Order Header
- Order Line (aka Order Detail)

A good example for you to learn from would be the classic [Northwind sample database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/linq/downloading-sample-databases) provided free of charge as a template for MS Access.

With the above structure, observe that each table serves a purpose with each record storing information pertaining to a **single entity** (whether it be a single *product*, single *customer*, single *order*, or single *order line*).

For example, you might have something like:

#### Products

- Primary Key: `Prd_ID`

```
+--------+-----------+-----------+
| Prd_ID | Prd_Desc  | Prd_Price |
+--------+-----------+-----------+
|      1 | Americano | $8.00     |
|      2 | Mocha     | $6.00     |
|      3 | Latte     | $5.00     |
+--------+-----------+-----------+
```

#### Customers

- Primary Key: `Cus_ID`

```
+--------+--------------+
| Cus_ID |   Cus_Name   |
+--------+--------------+
|      1 | Joe Bloggs   |
|      2 | Robert Smith |
|      3 | Lee Mac      |
+--------+--------------+
```

#### Order Header

- Primary Key: `Ord_ID`
- Foreign Keys: `Ord_Cust`

```
+--------+----------+------------+
| Ord_ID | Ord_Cust |  Ord_Date  |
+--------+----------+------------+
|      1 |        1 | 2020-02-16 |
|      2 |        1 | 2020-01-15 |
|      3 |        2 | 2020-02-15 |
+--------+----------+------------+
```

#### Order Line

- Primary Key: `Orl_Order` + `Orl_Line`
- Foreign Keys: `Orl_Order`, `Orl_Prod`

```
+-----------+----------+----------+---------+
| Orl_Order | Orl_Line | Orl_Prod | Orl_Qty |
+-----------+----------+----------+---------+
|         1 |        1 |        1 |       2 |
|         1 |        2 |        3 |       1 |
|         2 |        1 |        2 |       1 |
|         3 |        1 |        1 |       4 |
|         3 |        2 |        3 |       2 |
+-----------+----------+----------+---------+
```

You might also opt to store the product description & price on the order line records, so that these are retained at the point of sale, as the information in the `Products` table is likely to change over time.